# Running "pod update" gives segmentation fault 11 error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Running pod update on my current project returns the "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 error. while trying to compile Swift source files ... What would be the best way to debug in this case? (Try to uninstall each pod and see which is causing this error?) I did try removing derived data but it didn't remove the error.

The list of my pods are
    pod 'HockeySDK'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.8'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.8'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.8'
    pod 'Koloda'
    pod 'TagListView'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'

> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/BrowseViewController.swift
>       cd /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/EditProfileViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/APIDataQuery.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/CreateAccountViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TastiiTabBarViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TagColorEffectHandler.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/LoginViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/VenueMenuTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/UserManager.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ActivityCellDesigner.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/EditBasicInfoSettingsViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MenuItemTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsMenuTableView.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/FeedViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Item.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsNavigationController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIColorExtension.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SpecialsTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/FAQViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/PrivateInformationEditCell.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/TealSwitch.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MyMenuTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/VenueDetailViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/CustomOverlayView.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsSubSelectionViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Constants.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/DiscoverViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsMenuHeaderView.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/BrowseCardView.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Activity.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TastiiPaddedTextField.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsMenuTableViewDataSource.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MyTastePreferencesSettingsViewController.swift"
>   -primary-file "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/BrowseViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIViewExtension.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UserProfileViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIAlertControllerExtension.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/AppDelegate.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MyMenuViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MatchesAddViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ItemDetailViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ItemDetailViewControllerMapViewExtension.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SearchResultsViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/User.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TastiingRedeemActivity.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ActivityTableViewCell.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIImageViewExtension.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TasteMatchAddActivity.swift"
>   "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Venue.swift"
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
>   -I /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework"
>   -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii-Bridging-Header.h"
>   -module-cache-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D
>   DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc
>   -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc "-I/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Pods/Headers/Public" -Xcc
>   "-I/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Pods/Headers/Public/HockeySDK" -Xcc
>   -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App"
>   -emit-module-doc-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name Tastii -emit-module-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.o
>
> 0  swift                    0x0000000103f07fbb
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43 1  swift
>   0x0000000103f086fb SignalHandler(int) + 379 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8e531eaa _sigtramp + 26 3  swift
>   0x000000010268ae58 swift::NominalTypeDecl::prepareExtensions() + 40 4 
>   swift                    0x00000001021ce707
>   swift::SILWitnessVisitor<(anonymous
>   namespace)::SILGenConformance>::visitProtocolDecl(swift::ProtocolDecl*)
>   + 999 5  swift                    0x00000001021cbee5 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::getWitnessTable(swift::ProtocolConformance*)
>   + 277 6  swift                    0x000000010221b5b0 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 1264 7  swift
>   0x000000010221b04e
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*)
>   + 30 8  swift                    0x00000001021a3bdb swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*,
>   unsigned int) + 779 9  swift                    0x00000001021a4790
>   swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&,
>   swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional, bool, bool) + 928 10
>   swift                    0x00000001021a4b3d
>   swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&,
>   llvm::Optional, bool) + 109 11 swift
>   0x0000000101ff8992 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&,
>   swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef, int&) + 11442
>   12 swift                    0x0000000101ff5ad3
>   frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef, char const*, void*) + 2691
>   13 swift                    0x0000000101ff2154 main + 2324 14
>   libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff85a5b5ad start + 1 15 libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000000000079 start + 2052737741 Stack dump:
>   0.    Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/EditProfileViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/APIDataQuery.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/CreateAccountViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TastiiTabBarViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TagColorEffectHandler.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/LoginViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/VenueMenuTableViewCell.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/UserManager.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ActivityCellDesigner.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/EditBasicInfoSettingsViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MenuItemTableViewCell.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsMenuTableView.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/FeedViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Item.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsNavigationController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIColorExtension.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SpecialsTableViewCell.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/FAQViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/PrivateInformationEditCell.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/TealSwitch.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MyMenuTableViewCell.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/VenueDetailViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/CustomOverlayView.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsSubSelectionViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Constants.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/DiscoverViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsMenuHeaderView.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/BrowseCardView.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Activity.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TastiiPaddedTextField.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SettingsMenuTableViewDataSource.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MyTastePreferencesSettingsViewController.swift
>   -primary-file /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/BrowseViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIViewExtension.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UserProfileViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIAlertControllerExtension.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MyMenuViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/MatchesAddViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ItemDetailViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ItemDetailViewControllerMapViewExtension.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/SearchResultsViewController.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/User.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TastiingRedeemActivity.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/ActivityTableViewCell.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/UIImageViewExtension.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer
>   App/Tastii/TasteMatchAddActivity.swift
>   /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii/Venue.swift -target
>   x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
>   -I /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Pods/HockeySDK/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework
>   -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Tastii-Bridging-Header.h
>   -module-cache-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D
>   DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc
>   -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Tastii-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App/Pods/Headers/Public/HockeySDK -Xcc
>   -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/terrybu/Desktop/Tastii/Consumer App -emit-module-doc-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name Tastii -emit-module-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/terrybu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tastii-ewsztkbhbacmsvecxhabkfyvrozh/Build/Intermediates/Tastii.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tastii.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BrowseViewController.o

Comment: what version of pods are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worst comes to worst reintegrate pods by

1) deintegrate it "pod deintegrate"
https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

2) sudo gem uninstall pods and then reinstall it

3) remove Pod file directory 
remove Podfile.lock
and do a clean pod install

4) test pod update is now working,
all subsequent time you can do a pod update 
you can test and verify that it does not segfault after you install

Comment: Thank you ... I did kind of a brute force approach and started deleting files until I saw the error disappear. I saw that when I deleted an Extension i made on UIColorExtension.swift, the segmentation fault error did not appear again ... it was some swift code i had in there that interfered with one of the pods. very weird